# event listener in for loop is executing simultaneously instead of one at a time how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to figure this out. This is an example of what I'm struggling with.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  test();
  console.log("2");
}


function test() {
  document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", () =>
    console.log("1"));
}
```

```html
<button id="Button">BUTTON</button>
```

after pressing the button once, it will show the statement three times, and it'll show the "2" three times already in console. I want the "2" to show only after I've pressed the button, and for a single button press to only do a single iteration of test, i.e. show the "1" in console.

How would I do this? I've spent so long and can't figure this out.

Comment: Why you are calling the `test()` function in the for loop?

Comment: `console.log("2")` is part of the `for` loop. Of course it will run immediately. If want it to run after the click, add it it the event listener after `console.log("1")`

Answer (score 0):

Right now, what you're doing is running that loop with 3 iterations in the beginning. That means the 2 gets logged 3 times.
Also you are adding 3 eventListeners-functions to that button when the loop iterates in the beginning by calling test().
So when you click the button, the callback function in the addEventListener function should log 3 times the 1 if it does not get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Event listener has "once" parameter in the options if you need a function to fire only once. But if you need 3 times or more you can create a counter and remove event listener manually:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("Button")
let counter = 0

function test() {
  if (counter < 3) {
    console.log("2");
    counter++
  } else {
    button.removeEventListener("click", this)
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", (console.log("1"), test));
```

```html
<button id="Button">BUTTON</button>
```